# How to set connection timeouts in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, timeout

I use the following lines to get a web page from GAE, but it takes a long time, how to raise the timeout limit ?

```
try
{
  URL url=new URL(Url + "?r=" + System.currentTimeMillis());
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

  while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) { Result += line + "\n"; }
  reader.close();
}
catch (MalformedURLException e) { ... }
catch (IOException e) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE/J offers two APIs:

**Option 1.** The **java.net API**, where you can use the `URLConnection` (or [HttpURLConnection](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet.html#Using_HttpURLConnection)) class:

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMs);
conn.setReadTimeout(timeoutMs);
```

**Option 2.** The **GAE [Low Level API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/package-summary.html)** offers a `FetchOptions#setDeadline` method to set the deadline for the fetch request.

As a third alternative, you could also use a specific library such as [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/index.html), but you would have to check if  that library works with the inherent limitations of GAE/J.

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, connectionTimeoutMillis);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, socketTimeoutMillis);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```

Comment: Regarding Option (1) - quoting from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet#Java_Net_Features_Not_Supported - "The app cannot set explicit connection timeouts for the request." - So is this really an option?

Answer (score 1):

`url.openStream()` is just a shortcut to call `openConnection().getInputStream()` but without the possibility to set the proper timeout statements.

You should use the `openConnection()` method instead with something like this:

```
URL url=new URL(Url+"?r="+System.currentTimeMillis());
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMs);
conn.setReadTimeout(timeoutMs);
in = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the timeout, you have to use the [low level API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/package-summary.html). To do so, instantiate an `HttpRequest`, call `getFetchOptions()` on it, and call `setDeadline` on the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GAE/J SDK 1.4? If so, then Task Queue timing out in 30 sec instead of the promised 10 min. I believe you need to change something in queue.xml file. Also you can take a look this [mail-archive](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-appengine-java@googlegroups.com/msg16333.html)